# What are some of the more efficient ways of studying for an Olympiad?

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

This September I am participating in a competition called the Australian Intermediate Mathematics olympiad, and you may not have heard of it but it's very similar to the AIME. Could you please tell me how I could prepare for it well because I really want to do well.

I bought some math books on the internet and am studying them... is this a good way or preparing? These math books cover topics such as proving, number theory, combinatorics and so on... Here is a practice paper for the competition and I have done it many times. It is easy but I hope that this year's will be similar, however it is always better to preparing for it. => http://www.amt.edu.au/wuaimo.pdf

Edit: How much time should I be spending everyday practicing?

Comment: The Art of Problem Solving website may indeed come in handy in general, it really is a great source for learning about various methods of solving olympiad-like problems, with a bunch of problems with solutions as well. Here is the Olympiad Section, you might want to check the other sections too. There is a lot of information in the whole forum. http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewforum.php?f=217

Comment: @mathh Okay thank you very much for your reply but are you referring to the Alcumus part?

Comment: I'm referring to the forum, the link of which I've put into the comment.

Comment: You should go through this website: http://hcmop.wordpress.com/2012/03/23/how-to-approach-an-olympiad-problem-by-ho-jun-wei/

Comment: One or two facts presented here may be useful as well: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Resources/Papers/MildorfInequalities.pdf

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51666833/Problems%20and%20Theorems%202.pdf

Comment: A book on elementary number theory: https://archive.org/details/ElementaryNumberTheory

Comment: Knowing about such thing as Radical Axis may be useful in geometry. You can read about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_axis and here: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/blog/39836

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Years ago, I participated in one Mathematical Olympiad in my country (with very good result).

I bought a book with solved problems in this kind of contests. 
I tried to solve myself about 1 or 2 hours. After that, I read the book and compared solutions. 
Many times I didn't know anything to do, so reading the book I tried to learn many kind of strategies that are useful in diferent areas (Inequalities are essential in these sort of exams and also some common strategies, as induction, or reductio ad absurdum).
By doing that, I had something to try when I didn't know how to continue.

Good luck and don't try to learn solutiones by heart, only strategies.

Comment: This is very helpful thank you because before when I couldn't do a question I would be intrigued about what the solution is and look it up. But after reading the solution, a few days later I forget it. So you are saying that I should just keep on practicing questions? @juanito

Comment: Yes. @Geoff Don't worry if you forget solutions. When you'll have practised more, in many times you'll know different strategies to 'atack' the problem. As I said, study inequalities, congruences and write down methods of solving that you don't know...this may help!

Comment: Thank you but what are the best ways for me to practice proofs? I usually come across difficult proofing questions and end up looking at the proof. To learn this method should I write it out again and again until I remember it? @juanito

Comment: Solving a bunch of problems often bring up a lot of useful lemmas that you can memorize. There is a lot of methods for solving math problems and so you should get a good book that would cover them. I can mention some methods you should learn about in case you haven't heard of them: bounding a number between two consecutive squares when solving a diophantine-type equation to figure out the cases when the number can be a square, don't forget about modular arithmetic, comparing the sizes of two sides of an equation, factoring, may need to use the gcd's of numbers, etc.

Comment: I've put there some of the possible ways of solving diophantine or similar equations which are quite often seen in olympiad problems.

Comment: There are a lot of useful inequality lemmas such as $a^2+b^2+c^2\ge ab+bc+ca$, $(a+b+c)^2\ge 3(ab+bc+ca)$, etc.

Comment: That depends on you @Geoff, buy I wouldn't do that. When you don't know a method, you are not going to use it. By reading some solutions with them, you'll notice when they're usually applied and how. For example, when you want to proof a property $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, the best way is usually induction (obviously isn't the unique way). Other typical methods are proof by infinite descent, reduction ad absurdum, $A \Rightarrow B \Leftrightarrow not(B)\Rightarrow not(A)$...

Comment: Yes I understand but aren't diophantine equations polynomial equations? Yeah I have seen many modular arithmetic questions but they can get very complicating. I dont know to turn the question into a modular arithmetic form... @mathh

Comment: Yeah and I have only learnt Induction and contradiction (reduction ad absurdum) so far as I'm in grade 9. But those questions asking you to prove with geometrical constructions such as triangles and parallelograms are proved how? @juanito

Comment: There are not a fixed method...intuition is usually the key... so try to see some solutions and compare different exercises to see if an argument is used many times... Solving problems, as @mathh says, is really difficult...and can't be memorized...so practising a lot is the only way to train your brain to solve problems.

Comment: You simply check what kind of remainders on both sides of the equality you get. If you see that the remainders on the left-hand side and the right-hand side of the equality don't match up, then you know that the equality can't even hold and that means that the equation has no solutions. Using modular arithmetic for proving that an equation has no solutions is often successful. The arithmetic could also be used to determine some of the properties of some of the variables of the equation. E.g. you should try solving $x^2+8=3^n$ which involves using modular arithmetic to get some properties of n.

Comment: Okay because during those 4 hour long olympiads, time is usually not a problem - but the questions. I just cant think of how to solve some of them, as they use different theorems to work out. These need practice in some aspects of mathematics right? Such as inequalities, congruency, factorisation etc.

Comment: @mathh All I really know about modular arithmetic is the equations, e.g. 11 =congruent= 3 (mod 4) and other examples. Sorry but could you please explain x^2 + 8 = 3^n

Comment: I'll just show you the solution: check the equation $\pmod 4$. The number $3^0$ gives a remainder $1$, $3^1$ gives $3$, $3^2$ gives $1$. The cycle $1;3;1;3;1;3\ldots$ continues. Now you can try finding out yourself why a square always gives the remainders $0;1\pmod 4$... After some more analysis you'll simply notice that $n$ is even. But you should really study about some properties of modular arithmetic to fully understand this. This is a very simple example of how you could use it.

Comment: $8$ gives a remainder $0$, $x^2$ gives either $0$ or $1$ and $3^n$ gives either $1$ or $3$ shown by the pattern I've shown you in the last comments. Hence we have either of these: $$0+0\equiv1\pmod 4$$ $$1+0\equiv1\pmod 4$$ $$0+0\equiv3\pmod 4$$ $$1+0\equiv3\pmod 4$$
And you can see that the only case that is possible is the 2nd one.

Comment: Thanks I will try to practice it on some websites. I have a website here from AoPS: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Modular_arithmetic/Introduction#Sample_Problem but if you could give me any other website suggestions that would be very helpful.

Comment: Wait but isn't 5 ≡ 1 (mod 4) ? I dont see why 0+0≡1(mod4). because 0/4 = 0 and there is no remainder 1.

Comment: I never said that $0+0\equiv1\pmod 4$. I've written in the last comment that the $1+0\equiv1\pmod 4$ is the equivalence that holds.

Comment: You said this: 8 gives a remainder 0, x2 gives either 0 or 1 and 3n gives either 1 or 3 shown by the pattern I've shown you in the last comments. Hence we have either of these:
0+0≡1(mod4)
1+0≡1(mod4)
0+0≡3(mod4)
1+0≡3(mod4)
And you can see that the only case that is possible is the 2nd one. –  mathh 5 mins ago

Comment: oh wait sorry, i didnt see that you said 1+0≡1(mod4)

Comment: but I also dont understand why 1+0≡1(mod4)

Comment: Well, $1+0=1$, so we have $1\equiv 1\pmod 4$.

Comment: $a\equiv b\pmod c$ denotes the fact that $c\mid a-b$.

Comment: Yes I understand the modulo but not x2+8=3n. Could you explain how that relates to the modulo

Comment: You can try continuing the solution once you know that $n$ is even.

Comment: So c is divisible by a-b right? '∣' just means divisible

Comment: $\mid$ means 'divides ...'.

Comment: Okay please give me another example of modular arithmetic

Comment: @mathh I found a question about modular arithmetic that I have always had trouble with but maybe you could have a look and possibly solve it? => Find the 3-digit number at the right-hand ends of 1! + 2! + 3! + .... + 2008!

Comment: I've shown you the main methods. I could think of another problem for practice, but in a solution I wouldn't add much of the other ways you could use modular arithmetic. First of all, I leave you $x^2+8=3^{2n}$ to solve as an exercise. You won't need to use modular arithmetic for the solution. And the AoPS will give you some practice with using modular arithmetic.

Comment: Just in case AoPS doesn't cover it, you could learn about the Fermat's Little Theorem which involves modular arithmetic, as well as the Euler Theorem.

Comment: I am not sure how I would solve it. You can add this question to Math.SE (or AoPS) for professionals to answer if there's no other way you could solve it.

Comment: Thanks for your help @mathh. I think its most suitable for me to learn just Fermat's little theorem and not the Euler Theorem.

Comment: is it 1 ≡3 (mod 8)?

Comment: You don't have $8\mid 1-3=-2$, so no, it is not.